# Trying to my arrays with pointers but it doesnt work

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

My arrays that i pass into my constructor only allows my pointers to create arrays of only size 4

```
int* Array1;
int* Array2;
Sort::Sort(int acrray[]){
    Array1 = new int[size(acrray)]();
    cout << sizeof(*Array1);
    Array2 = new int[size(acrray)]();
    for(int index = 0; index < sizeof(acrray);index++){
         Array1[index] = acrray[index];
         cout << index << endl;
         Array2[index] = acrray[index];
    }
}
```

This is the test case:

```
int arrays[] = {5,7,3,5,1,24,5};
Sort n(arrays);
```

Here is my output:
[Code Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aYds9.jpg)

Comment: this appears to be C++ code but I am not a C++ developer. My point is that you should tag the question correctly.

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish here? do you wanna get the number of elements stored in your array?

Answer (score 2):

`sizeof(*Array)` is actually `sizeof(int)`.

```
void foo(int acrray[]) {
    cout << sizeof(acrray);
}
```

will always print 4 (or 8 on 64bit machines). this is not an array in the function arguments, despite its look, but rather a pointer. you should add an argument for the array size:

```
void foo(int acrray[], size_t len) ...
```

besides, `sizeof(array)` will not give you the length of the array, but the size it is occupying in memory.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an array, then ONLY if you created it in the same method, you can write

`sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0])`

to get the number of elements in the array. But as this only works if you created it in the same method, it's pointless - once you pass your array to any other place in your program it 'decays' to being treated like a pointer type, and afterwards `sizeof(array)` will be equivalent to `sizeof(*int)` (or whatever your array's element type is). So, if you are passing an array around you need to pass its length with it as a separate parameter.

To demonstrate the decay of array to pointer, the following C code:

```
int sizeofarray(int array[])
{
    return sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]);
}

int main()
{
    int myarray[] = {1, 2, 3};
    printf("%d\n", sizeof(myarray)/sizeof(myarray[0]));
    printf("%d\n", sizeofarray(myarray));
    return 0;
}
```

Produces this output:

```
3
1
```

Comment: No, it won't. `sizeof(acraray)` is `sizeof(int *)`, see the other answer.